# BBcode parsing problem

Tags: php

Im building my own forum where you can use diffrent types of BBcode and one of them is [youtube][/youtube] to embed youtube videos,

The idea is to make it idiot-proof, the user can enter the full lenght url or just the code to the video like this

> [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]
>   [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg&feature=related[/youtube]
>   [youtube]AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]

Here is my code that get the code out of a full lenght url,

```
<?php
$getpost=$_POST['post'];  
$getpost=preg_replace("'\[youtube\].*?=(.*?)&.*?\[/youtube\]'is",'yt link is \\1',$getpost);  
$getpost=preg_replace("'\[youtube\].*?=(.*?)\[/youtube\]'is",'yt link is \\1',$getpost);  
$getpost=preg_replace("'\[youtube\](.*?)\[/youtube\]'is",'yt link is \\1',$getpost);  
?>
```

The results are:

> yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg
>   yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg
>   yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg

It works perfectly if I only want to embed 3 youtube videos,

But if i wanted to embed 6 youtube videos like this:

> [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]
>   [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg&feature=related[/youtube]   [youtube]AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]
>   [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]
>   [youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg&feature=related[/youtube]
>   [youtube]AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]

The results are:

> yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg
>   yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg[/youtube]
>   yt link is AJ3_kndmeCg
>   yt link is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ3_kndmeCg
>   [youtube]AJ3_kndmeCg

Do you see that^^ the tags still remain on two lines and one of the lines show a full lenght URL,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was a real toughie of a regex to write.

Got it for you in one:

```
$getpost=preg_replace('@\[youtube\].*?(?:v=)?([^?&[]+)(&[^[]*)?\[/youtube\]@is',
             'yt link is \\1', $getpost);
```

This will work for all the cases you supplied.  It will *not* work if the link begins with a part other than 'v=' (for example, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?foo=bar&v=AJ3_kndmeCg').

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks, works really well no matter how many videos the user embeds, this is idiot-proof for the users, thank you very much

Comment: No matter how clever the regexp is (I love to hack regexps myself!), this is the opposite of idiot-proof for the developer(s) :-/

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather use an existing BBCode parsing library like http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/php/bbcode/index_en.html which also allows you to define your own bb tags, and turn them into the HTML you want.

;)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thank you! Tony the pony will not pay a visit to you when you fall asleep at night.